# Help me save a dying tree

Tags: plant-health

I have lived on property for about 12 years. This red tree has been slowly losing leaves every year. Last year was a drought in new England and i though that was the issue. This summer season we have had plenty of rain. Still this red tree look just as bad if not worse.

Can someone recommend how I can save this tree. It also has this blue green growth on the bark.

[image: Tree with dying leaves]